# why is the account managed by AccountManager is delete automatically?

Tags: android, accountmanager

My little App creates an account in AccountManager. But if i move the App from internal storage to SD card, the account is automatically delete by AccountManagerService if i unmounted the SD card or reboot the machine.

does anyone have any idea about this ? does this mean we cannot move the App to SD card or is it because i am missing some config attributes in the config xml ?

D/AccountManagerService(  245): deleting account XXX because type com.XXX no longer has a registered authenticator
D/ContactsProvider(  945): removing data for removed account Account {name=XXXX, type=com.XXX}

Comment: How are you moving it?  Using FroYo's built in "Move to SD" function, or using a third party solution like AppsToSD?

Answer (score 5):

see the reply from dianne hackborn on android-developers:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/RqO6NGdgYPY/3K8GDsbNOyoJ